# Can I Use SlideToggle() on Divs with Display set to Table-Cell?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

In my page, I have a hierarchy of div's that are set to `display: table` with child div's set to `display:table-cell`.  I want to `slideToggle()` on a given cell to replace its contents.  I have read that `slideToggle` toggles the display between `none` and `block`, so likely `table-cell` is out of its scope.

Firstly: is this true that I cannot use `slideToggle()` with Table-Cell objects?

Secondly: before I redesign everything to not make use of Table-Cells, is there a work-around that I could take advantage of?

This code snippet demonstrates the behaviour (that I don't like).  As you can see, the nice sliding toggle behaviour does not happen.  Instead, the cell briefly appears next to the previous cell that is supposed to disappear, rather than sliding up vertically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">

.container {
    display: table;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="$('.cell').slideToggle('slow'); return false;" >Click Me</button>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cell">Here is a test</div>
        <div class="cell" style="display: none">Test2</div> 
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="common/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="common/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Other Scripts -->
    <script src="common/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gdbjohnson/8x8e1gyx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is tricky. `slideToggle` will work on `table-cell` elements putting the element in the previous state. Documentation says:

> The display property is saved and restored as needed. If an element
>   has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once
>   again be displayed inline. When the height reaches 0 after a hiding
>   animation, the display style property is set to none to ensure that
>   the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

The problem is that the element won't animate properly because `slideToggle` tries to animate element's height and height of `table-cell` could never be lower than content size.

So the answer is yes slideToggle will work on `table-cell` but no it won't animate properly.

Reference: [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: 2nd part of my question: Is there a work-around that I could take advantage of that you know of?  I'm not required to use slideToggle(), but I want it's effect while hopefully using table-cell.  Essentially, having an overlay animate overtop of the existing table-cell

Comment: nevermind on the 2nd part.  I decided that a work-around will make it unnecessarily complicated.  I decided to re-design it to avoid the table-cell